# can't find rhodes, need version 3.2.0 or greater

Tags: rhodes

I just started with Rhodes cross platform mobile application development. I followed the rhostudio tutorial to install RhoStudio and to start creating a Rhodes application.

Once I click the Finish button in create new project wizard I get an error message:

Cannot find Rhodes, need rhodes version equal or greater 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

That's because /YOURPATH/bin/ruby is not in the PATH, you have two choices:

1. add that to PATH
2. run your eclipse from terminal.(only if you are using rvm, for PATH
   is modified by rvm when start from shell, start eclipse from GUI won't
   work.)